# How can I get PythonInterpreter to recognize datetime and other modules such as psutils in python?

Tags: python, jython, system-properties, jython-2.5, pythoninterpreter

I am running a python program called diagnostics.py from a java class called PyInterpreter that intializes a jython PythonInterpreter object and a file to use and can run methods from that python program. My python program looks like this:

```py
import datetime
import psutil

class HeartbeatGenerator:
    ...
```

and when I try to run this program, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../../eclipse-workspace/Diagnostics/diagnostics.py", line 2, in <module>
    import datetime
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

I have installed datetime and psutil with pip and they are in /usr/local/bin/python3.7/site-packages as well as /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages. I have also copied and pasted the necessary files from that location into my jython.2.5.3/lib/site-packages, and in my PyInterpreter file, I have tried setting my system properties for python.home and python.path as seen:

```py
public PyInterpreter()  
       {  
          Properties props = System.getProperties();
          props.setProperty("python.home", "⁨/usr/local/lib/python3.7⁩⁩");
          props.setProperty("python.path", "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages");
          System.out.print(props);
          PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(),  
                                       props, 
                                       new String[0]);  

          this.interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();  
       }
```

but no matter what I set the sys properties to, I still get the same error. Right now it is only on the line to import datetime, but I know if I had `import psutil` first, it would break on that line too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just had to add what needed to be on the sys.path to the PYTHONPATH variable in my bash_profile, so that it would add that to the sys.path variable for jython.